# Google Maps and address

Tags: django, google-maps

I would like on my site to give users the ability to add google maps but in a way that was enough to enter the address (city, street, number). I will do this on Django.

How to do it easy?

Comment: Is that a question or a sentence which gives a "Hope", Sorry way too vague...Please rephrase vague question

Comment: I don't get the question, what exactly do yo want to do?

Comment: user on admin panel write in form address (ie. 
Georgetown University, Resevoir Rd., NW, Washington D.C., DC 20007) and on site will be shown google map at this point

Comment: This has not much to do with Django: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nips,

This is pretty easy to do. Check out this little project I've got on GitHub that does what you're asking:

https://github.com/johnfmorton/Get-That-LatLng

This uses Google's geocoding service from the Maps API:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

You provide it with an address and it returns an array of points on a map (latitude and longitude coordinates).